# offline access to data and sync when online

Tags: couchdb, offlineapps

Im having a website running on Joomla and mysql server at the backend.
The customers Im serving are some time at sea and disconnected from network. However they still need to have access to some of data for view and edit (add/change/delete).

I was thinking to implement a mobile app - based on titanium or phonegap and couchdb as bacend to sync data modifications.

But probably it's no good since I also require access for notebooks.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know JavaScript you could take a look at a project I've been working on, to sum it up quickly it's a basic version control system wrote in JavaScript which gives you the offline editing, tracking changes, retrieving what's changed locally and a way to put remote change into the local version.

The code itself is very decoupled but there is a server implemented in the MongoDB branch.  I'm working on a connection manager to detect connections and re-sync when it can.

The project is based at https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt

Thanks

Comment: Altough im looking for a solution that will also encapsulate the state im in (offline/online), it looks promising. I'll investigate it.